# How to check react component instance

Tags: node.js, react-router

I have some code:

```
export default function universalRouter(location, history, store) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Router.run(routes, location, [createTransitionHook(store)], (error, initialState, transition) => {                    
                const component = (<Provider store={store}
                    key = 'provider' > {() => < Router{...initialState}  
                    children = {routes}/>} < /Provider>);
                    return resolve({
                        component,
                        isRedirect: false
                    });

                });
        });
}
```

and some routes:

```
<Route>
   ...
   <Route path='*' component={NotFound}/>
</Route>
```

How to check in this code component resolve NotFound, maybe instanceof Notfound, version of react-router v1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function universalRouter(location, history, store) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Router.run(routes, location, [createTransitionHook(store)], (error, initialState, transition) => {                    
                const component = (<Provider store={store}
                    key = 'provider' > {() => < Router{...initialState}  
                    children = {routes}/>} < /Provider>);
                    return resolve({
                        component,
                        isRedirect: true
                    });

                });
        });
}
```